# Batch file runs fine in command prompt but gives error when double-clicked

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that accepts store numbers and sets them to an array and then iterates through the array. When I double click my batch file it gives the error:

```
256 was unexpected at this time.
```

But when I run it from the console/command prompt it runs fine.

Here is my code.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set index=0

:getstore
set /a index=index + 1
set /P store[%index%]=Enter SLC store number: 

:ask
set /P answer=Do you want to enter another store number (Y/N): 


if /i "%answer%" == "n" (
    set length=%index%
    goto next
)

if /i "%answer%" == "y" (
    goto getstore 
) else goto ask

:next
for /L %%i in (1,1,%length%) do (
    if %store% LSS 256 (
        for /L %%k in (1,1,5) do ping 192.168.!store[%%i]!.%%k -n 1 |find "TTL"
    )
    if %store% GTR 255 (    
        set /a store=%store% - 255
        for /L %%k in (1,1,5) do ping 10.0.!store[%%i]!.%%k -n 1 |find "TTL"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks MC ND!

Your comment got me thinking.

When I was calling store in the if statement I needed to use the !! and also the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double click a batch file, a new `cmd` instance will be executed, one instance where `store` has not been initialized, so the line

```
if %store% LSS 256 (
```

fails as `%store%` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MC ND!

Your comment got me thinking.

When I was calling store in the if statement I needed to use the !! and also the index.

This is my edited (now working) code:

```
:next
for /L %%i in (1,1,%length%) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%j in ("%store[%%i]%") do set store[%%i]=%%j
    if !store[%%i]! LSS 256 (
        for /L %%k in (1,1,5) do ping 192.168.!store[%%i]!.%%k -n 1 |find "TTL"
    )
    if !store[%%i]! GTR 255 (   
        set /a store=%store% - 255
        for /L %%k in (1,1,5) do ping 10.0.!store[%%i]!.%%k -n 1 |find "TTL"
    )
)
```